# What type of neural network is used for image style transfer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Tell me, please how to train a neural network to redraw pictures of people under the style of artists?
For example
Leonardo DiCaprio as Vincent van Gogh's Self-Portrait.[image]

I want to understand:

1. What type of neural network is used for this?
2. What type data are needed to train neural network?
3. What should be the format of data?

Where can I find any information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with style transfer, a technique in which the application of convolutional neural networks is quiet common. I believe the most relevant paper in this subject is by [Gatys et. al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576), which states:

> The class of Deep Neural Networks that are most powerful in image
>   processing tasks are called Convolutional Neural Networks.
>   Convolutional Neural Networks consist of layers of small computational
>   units that process visual information hierarchically in a feed-forward
>   manner.

[This post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/neural-style-transfer-creating-art-with-deep-learning-using-tf-keras-and-eager-execution-7d541ac31398) by the TensorFlow team has a great tutorial on how to start with it. There's also [this really famous repo](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) with a Torch implementation.

Comment: thank you. I marked as answer, but Off-top question, is  style transfer technique  exist for R?

Comment: TensorFlow has R support. If you Google for it you'll find a bunch of references. [This is an example](https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-09-10-eager-style-transfer/)

Comment: You have already helped so much. But if you have any ideas, I would be glad.

Comment: @Julia ideas on what?